# Optimising LSTM using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Working on LSTM using Keras with a csv data model that looks like this

[image]

I train it with the code below

```python
import numpy as np
def to_sequences(seq_size, obs):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(len(obs)-SEQUENCE_SIZE-1):
        #print(i)
        window = obs[i:(i+SEQUENCE_SIZE)]
        after_window = obs[i+SEQUENCE_SIZE]
        window = [[x] for x in window]
        #print("{} - {}".format(window,after_window))
        x.append(window)
        y.append(after_window)

    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

# Read from time series file
path = "../data/"
filename = os.path.join(path,"series-31-spring-2018.csv")    
df = pd.read_csv(filename) 

df_train = df[df['time']<3000]
df_test = df[df['time']>=3000]

series_train = df_train['time'].tolist()
series_test = df_test['time'].tolist()

SEQUENCE_SIZE = 5
x_train,y_train = to_sequences(SEQUENCE_SIZE,series_train)
x_test,y_test = to_sequences(SEQUENCE_SIZE,series_test)

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

try: #try to load model
    model = load_model('lstm_model.h5')
except:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(64, dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.0,input_shape=(None, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(32))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),callbacks=[monitor, checkpointer],verbose=2,epochs=1000)
    model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model
    model.save('lstm_model.h5')

pred = model.predict(x_test)
score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(pred,y_test))
print("Score (RMSE): {}".format(score))
```

according to the expectation of the instructor I should easily get an RSME of below 1.0

but here's what I get after training (last lines)

```python
2s - loss: 410.1664 - val_loss: 401517.8173
Epoch 65/1000
2s - loss: 520.6698 - val_loss: 375924.9199
Epoch 66/1000
2s - loss: 1355.2032 - val_loss: 492885.1170
Epoch 67/1000
2s - loss: 3204.2609 - val_loss: 447782.5190
Epoch 68/1000
3s - loss: 3294.2978 - val_loss: 496805.7923
Epoch 69/1000
2s - loss: 3444.5545 - val_loss: 444395.7890
Epoch 70/1000
3s - loss: 13189.3451 - val_loss: 474823.9772
Epoch 71/1000
3s - loss: 3226.2044 - val_loss: 423853.1303
Epoch 72/1000
3s - loss: 2631.8741 - val_loss: 406473.1768
Epoch 00071: early stopping
Score (RMSE): 565.5713449009472
```

what can I change to get a better mean squared error? Have done some tinkering but it hasn't brought it significantly down so I'm guessing there's a key thing I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

After graphing both values I time which goes from 0-3999 and value which goes from 10-15 and expected to be predicted is "overwhelmed" by the large variance and digits of time. Switching it the values of time to z-score did bring the RSME down to 0.007